# The limit $\lim_{x \to ∞} (3x^4-5x^2+1)(1-e^{1/x^2})^2$

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x \to ∞} (3x^4-5x^2+1)(1-e^{1/x^2})^2$

I found +∞ but the limit is 3. How to compute this limit ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you explain how you got to the result $+\infty$?

Comment: hint: Taylor expend the exponential term

Comment: with developpement, but i really don't how to simplify this function...

Comment: I don't understand your hint, sorry

Comment: How to expend this ?

Comment: I'm searching but I still don't understand. I do my best

Comment: What is the formula, what is the trick?

Comment: Use $e^{x} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{k}/k!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing  $x^2$ by $t,$ your limit
becomes $$\lim_{t \to \infty} 3t^2(1-e^{1/t})^2.$$
Now let $s=\frac{1}{t}$ so that the limit becomes
$$\lim_{s \to 0^+} 3(\frac{1-e^s}{s})^2=3(-1)^2=3.$$

Comment: I think you meant $\lim_{t\to\infty}(3t^2-5t+1)\left(1-e^{\frac1t}\right)^2$?

Comment: No.  Multiply the first factor by $t^2$ and then divide each of its subterms by $t^2$ to understand what happens as $t$ approaches infinity.

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle \lim_{ x \to \infty} (3x^4-5x^2+1)(1-e^{1/x^2})^2$
$=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{e^{1/x^2}-1}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)^2\left(\frac{3x^4-5x^2+1}{x^4}\right)$
$=1\times 3$

You know that: $$\lim_{u \to 0^+} \frac{e^u-1}{u}=1$$
Putting $u=1/x^2$ we get:$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\frac{1}{x^2}}-1}{\frac{1}{x^2}}=1$$

Comment: the power 2 is missing

Comment: This is a bit unclear it wiuld be helpful if you would show how you got from one step to the other

Comment: Why did you divide this by 1/x^2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $e^{x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^{k}/k!$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (3x^4 - 5x^2 + 1) (1 - e^{1/x^2})^{2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} (3x^{4} - 5x^{2} + 1)\left(x^{-4} + \mathcal{O}(x^{-6})\right) = \boxed{3} $$

Comment: what is the meaning of the big O ?

Comment: It means that all of the terms after $x^{-4}$ are at most $x^{-6}$. The full expansion is $x^{-4} + x^{-6} + x^{-8} + \cdots$, but we can ignore the terms other than $x^{-4}$ in the limit.